# com.influxdb.exceptions.BadRequestException: compilation failed: error @1:1-1:149: expected RPAREN, got EOF

Tags: influxdb

com.influxdb.exceptions.BadRequestException: compilation failed: error @1:1-1:149: expected RPAREN, got EOF

error @1:14-1:149: got unexpected token in string expression @1:149-1:149: EOF

com.influxdb.exceptions.BadRequestException: compilation failed: error @1:1-1:149: expected RPAREN, got EOF

error @1:14-1:149: got unexpected token in string expression @1:149-1:149: EOFdd

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.